# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting - Python 3.6 - Conta de energia

Tags: python, string, syntax-error

Sou iniciante na área e durante os estudos de programação em Python fiquei travado neste exercício, sendo o objetivo aparecer na tela do usuário quanto ele deve pagar por kwh utilizados, dependendo se for para comércio, indústria ou residência, tendo taxas diferentes dependendo do limite específico.

```
    w = float(input("Qual o valor de kWh consumidos? "))
    i = input("Qual o tipo de instalação elétrica? Digite R para residências, I para indústrias ou C para comércios: ")
    if i == "R":
      if w<=500:
      print("O valor a ser pago pelo fornecimento de energia é de R$%5.2f." % (w*0,40))
      else:
    print("O valor a ser pago pelo fornecimento de energia é de R$%5.2f." % (w*0,65))
    elif i == "I":
      if w<=5000:
      print("O valor a ser pago pelo fornecimento de energia é de R$%5.2f." % (w*0,55))
      else:
      print("O valor a ser pago pelo fornecimento de energia é de R$%5.2f." % (w*0,60))
    elif i == "C":
      if w<=1000:
      print("O valor a ser pago pelo fornecimento de energia é de R$%5.2f." % (w*0,55))
      else:
      print("O valor a ser pago pelo fornecimento de energia é de R$%5.2f." % (w*0,60))
   else:
   print("Por gentileza, escolha uma das 3 opções digitando corretamente entre R, I e C.")
```

Como sou iniciante, ficarei muito grato por qualquer dica caso algo esteja errado. Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Tente começar trocando as vírgulas por ponto:
..gia é de R$%5.2f." % (w*0.40))

Comment: Nossa... como não enxerguei isso, que vergonha. Obrigado!!!

Comment: Já que você está começando agora sugiro que comece já pelo Python 3. As diferenças quanto ao Python 2 deixa o aprendizado muito mais fácil